# Find elements in array such that inf < element < sup in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Given an array of unsorted points I need to replace those in a given interval. Easiest way I think of is

```
import numpy as np

def v1(array,inf,sup):
    for i in range(len(array)):
        if inf<array[i]<sup:
            array[i]-=10
    return array
```

I was suggested to use `np.where`. It works smoothly if there is only one boolean condition:

```
def v2(array,sup):
    array[np.where(array < sup)[0]]-=10
    return array
```

But the same setup with `inf` and `sup` value, i.e.

```
array[np.where(inf < array < sup)[0]]-=10
```

will raise an error

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous.
Use a.any() or a.all().
```

I have to do something clumsy like using `np.where` twice with two conditions and intersecate the two resulting indexes arrays...

```
def v2(array,inf,sup):
    i=list(set.intersection(set(np.where(array>inf)[0]),set(np.where(array<sup)[0])))
    array[i]-=10
    return array
```

Suggestions?

Comment: Not great, but better: You could ues `A[[inf < x < sup for x in A]] -= 10`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `&` to have multiple conditions with `np.where`:

```
array[np.where((inf < array) & (array < sup))[0]] -= 10
```

Or without `np.where`:

```
array[(inf < array) & (array < sup)] -= 10
```

Comment: Do you actually need `np.where`? `A[(inf < A) & (A < sup)]` works as well.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could also use a list comprehension as the index and use comparison chaining for each element in the comprehension.

```
>>> A = np.array([i*10 for i in range(10)])
>>> inf, sup = 30, 70
>>> A[[inf < x < sup for x in A]] *= 10
>>> A
array([  0,  10,  20,  30, 400, 500, 600,  70,  80,  90])
```

In the given example, using `&` as in the other answer works just as well, if not better, but this might be more universally applicable, e.g. for checking some function on each value.